# Gulp-concat can't concat file

Tags: javascript, gulp-concat

Here is my directory structure：

```
- javascript
  |- file2.js
- output
- file1.js
- gulpfile.js
```

And I want to merge `file1.js` and `file2.js`. Here is my `gulpfile.js` content:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('javascript', function () {
    return gulp.src('./javascript/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('file1.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./output/'));
});
```

however, the concat result is confusing me, the file in output directory is called `file1.js`, and the content in the file is only from origin `file2`, so I have some questions:

- How can I decide the ouput file name?
- Why the content don't merged? How can I make them merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concat pipe takes as a parameter the name of the output file. The following should work:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('javascript', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./javascript/file2.js', './file1.js'])
        .pipe(concat('concatenatedFile.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./output/'));
});
```

EDIT: I updated the answer so that I explicitly show how to have the two files you want as the source files.

Comment: Would make sense to include a version where we can use *.js too? Looks like he just needs to copy thr file2 to the javascript folder :)